# Mysql - Consulta Recursiva para obter apenas as categorias-pai

Tags: mysql

eu tenho a seguinte tabela `category`:

```
id | desc_cat       | parent_id
19 | Pessoais       | (null)
20 | Cartao Credito | 19
21 | Academia       | 19
22 | Residencia     | (null)
23 | Agua           | 22
24 | Luz            | 22
25 | Aluguel        | 22
```

E tenho a tabela contendo lançamentos com nome `cashbook`:

```
id  | value    | category_id
177 | 480.55   | 20
178 | 100.00   | 24
179 | 580.00   | 25
180 | 80.00    | 21
181 | 28.00    | 23
```

Preciso fazer uma consulta em `cashbook` e retornar os valores somados e agrupados pela categoria pai (onde está como `null`), por exemplo:

```
Categoria-Pai | Total
Pessoais      | 560,55
Residencia    | 708
```

Podem me ajudar a montar essa consulta?? Peguei alguns exemplos de consultas recursivas mas estou muito perdido. Meu sistema está sendo feito em PHP (Yii framework).

Comment: Bem vindo ao MySQL, o grande elefante branco, o unico grande SGBD que não dá suporte à window function and common table expressions

Comment: Certo. Bom nesse caso, preciso saber se há uma forma simples de fazer, pois estou usando uma hospedagem compartilhada e não tenho acesso avançado ao BD. Conhece alguma forma @TobyMosque ?

Comment: Esses valores que pretende colocar no pai, encontram-se onde ? Qual tabela e em que coluna dessa tabela ? E quando fala em soma de valores, quer somar que valores ?

Espero que lhe consiga ajudar, mas neste momento ainda não comprieendi o que quer colocar onde estão os valores a null.

Comment: @SoeiroMass onde está armazenado como `null`, significa que é um registro pai, caso contrario iria conter algum ID de algum outro registro pai

Comment: @gugoan A minha questão é na tabela exemplo que colocou, na linha correspondente aos "Pessoais" tem um total de 560,55 e esse numero é composto por uma soma de valores da tabela "cashbook", mas que campos é que são somados ? Resumidamente qual é o campo que quer descobrir e onde estão os dados para que se possam somar, para obter o valor? E quais eles são? Tambem sugiro que reveja alguns conseitos sobre mysql, o que são tabelas mãe, coluna, linha, tabela e etc, iram lhe ajudar na hora de colocar questões e elas seram melhor entendidas, se forem colocadas com os termos correctos. Espero ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Obrigado pessoal, o SQL abaixo resolveu meu problema:

```
SELECT y.desc_category as segment, sum( x.value) as total FROM (
SELECT category.id_category, category.desc_category, category.parent_id , c.value AS value
FROM category
INNER JOIN cashbook AS c ON category.id_category = c.category_id )AS x 
INNER JOIN category AS y ON x.parent_id = y.id_category
INNER JOIN user AS u ON y.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = 3
GROUP BY y.desc_category
```

Answer (score 0):

gugoan, como eu disse na comentario, se o MySQL desse suporte à CTE, a consulta seria bem mais simples, em todo caso, gostaria que na sua proxima pergunta sobre SQL, você preparasse um SQLFiddle como este: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/add59/1

Node que as suas categorias foram uma arvore com apenas dois niveis, então todas as olhas estão diretamente ligados a raiz, neste caso um simples `LEFT JOIN` com `COALESCE` deve funcionar.

```
SELECT
  id,
  desc_cat,
  SUM(value)
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COALESCE(CatParent.id, Category.id) id, 
    COALESCE(CatParent.desc_cat, Category.desc_cat) desc_cat,
    CashBook.value
  FROM CashBook
  JOIN Category ON CashBook.category_id = Category.id
  LEFT JOIN Category AS CatParent ON Category.parent_id = CatParent.id
) AS CatParent
GROUP BY id, desc_cat
```

Porém esta abordagem só vai funcionar nesta situação, se a sua arvore for mais profunda, você terá problemas... por exemplo... se a sua tabela `Category` tiver os seguintes dados:

```
| id |            desc_cat | parent_id |
|----|---------------------|-----------|
| 26 |         Categoria 1 |    (null) |
| 27 |   Sub Categoria 1.1 |        26 |
| 28 | Sub Categoria 1.1.1 |        27 |
| 29 | Sub Categoria 1.1.2 |        27 |
| 30 |   Sub Categoria 1.2 |        26 |
| 31 | Sub Categoria 1.2.1 |        30 |
| 32 | Sub Categoria 1.2.2 |        30 |
```

Eu até tentei emular uma consulta recursiva usando `CTE` utilizando `View` ou uma `Function` com `MySQL`... porém não consegui faze-lo no `SQLFiddle`, acredito que o `MySQL` não suporta este tipo de estrutura.

Você ainda pode utilizar um `WHILE` para tentar fazer alguma coisa, mas o seu `MySQL` não vai conseguir inferir um plano de execução, a sua consulta vai ficar complexa. Só lhe aconselharia fazer isto para uma JOB agendada.

Porém como estes dados vão ser consumidos no PHP, o ideal será fazer este tipo de controle direto no PHP... infelizmente não sei o suficente de PHP para lhe dá um exemplo, porém posso atualizar esta resposta com um trecho de Codigo em C# ou JavaScript, então você poderia fazer um port desta logica para PHP.

Comment: Me deu uma luz... vou refazer aqui e postar o que eu consegui...